# Radial Gradient not showing correctly in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, radial-gradients

I have the following SVG with radialGradient as stroke ;

```html
<svg width="174" height="148" viewBox="0 0 174 148" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path
    d="M150.03 140.77C162.4 126.28 169.87 107.48 169.87 86.94C169.87 41.14 132.74 4 86.93 4C41.12 4 4 41.13 4 86.93C4 109.04 12.65 129.13 26.75 143.99"
    stroke="url(#paint0" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
<defs>
    <radialGradient id="paint0" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        gradientTransform="translate(86.9404 85.5195) rotate(90) scale(82.5 81.5403)">
        <stop offset="0.162057" stop-color="#F03944" />
        <stop offset="0.220719" stop-color="#FECA24" />
        <stop offset="0.347227" stop-color="#F2878D" />
        <stop offset="0.440938" stop-color="#C173FE" />
        <stop offset="0.633595" stop-color="#C173FE" />
        <stop offset="0.749274" stop-color="#076CFB" />
        <stop offset="0.868283" stop-color="#076CFC" />
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Yet the only color showing is the last color: #076CFC.
I've searched the internet and apparently it had something to do with the ids but as you can see I've kept these as simple as possible and it's still not working.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for a conic gradient but SVG doesn't have such a thing.

Comment: damn that explains alot...